# How can I add files to the hidden files list in Windows 10 locally without modifying the file?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, file-extension, hidden-file

If anybody else has used AutoCAD before, I'm sure you're well aware that it generates an enormous number of backup files (.bak). This is great and useful because it's a bloated program prone to crashing now and then. However, they're an eyesore when trying to look for stuff.

Now, I could change the file attributes with the "+h" or "-h" in the command line, however because these files are on a network drive they're accessible to other people who may need to access them in the future. Therefore I cannot modify the file properties in any way so that they remain as-is on other people's machines.

Comment: Short answer: You can't  (add files to the hidden files list in Windows 10 locally without modifying the file?)

Comment: Why not raise a request with Autodesk to have the backup files destination be configurable?

Comment: I can think of a kludge that would let you use the **Explorer** interface with only certain file types displayed. Ever noticed the *FileType* doplist in an `Open File` dialog? You can create one with a custom filter and launch it from **PowerShell**. Since double-clicking mimics clicking the `Open` button and closes the dialog,  code could execute the default action for the selected file and then loop to re-display the dialog -- functioning as a customized **Explorer** until you close the **PowerShell** parent. If you like that idea, I'll compose an answer later tonght...